# Looking for a Hydra/Json-ld serializer using attributes or extending json.net library

Tags: c#, .net, json, json-ld, hydra-core

I am looking for (or will create one) a library (in .net C#) that will serialize Json Object using attributes on properties of the POCO. I looked at this one, but it is still in preview and does not seem active anymore :

https://github.com/NuGet/json-ld.net

If you have any knowledge in that area, please let me know.

Edit:
I think the best way is To implement a Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter that will check for attributes on my object and then serialize it accordingly

Answer (score 1):

I think [RomanticWeb](http://romanticweb.net/) does more or less what you are looking for (it doesn't support Hydra yet AFAICT). Source code is available on GitHub: https://github.com/MakoLab/RomanticWeb